# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple with functions

Tags: python, function, csv

I am using functions to code a Shopping list. The user is asked questions like the name of the object, the quantity, the shop they will buy it from and the price of it. These are then added to a csv file. The user can ask for the total price so that they see how much they will spend.

Here is my code:

```
def TotalCost():
ViewItem = ViewList()
with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\ShoppingList.csv") as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile)#delimeter=',')
    TotalCost=0
    for i in range(1,3):
        TotalCost=TotalCost+int(ViewItem[i,3])

def ViewList():
    with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\ShoppingList.csv") as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile)#,delimeter=',')
        for row in reader:
            ItemView.append(row)
        return ItemView
```

Here is other code which correspomds to the issue:

```
elif ModeChose=='C':
TotalCost()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sophie\Documents\Sophie\Homework\Year 11\Computer Science\ShoppingList.py", line 106, in <module>
    TotalCost()
  File "C:\Users\sophie\Documents\Sophie\Homework\Year 11\Computer Science\ShoppingList.py", line 18, in TotalCost
    TotalCost=TotalCost+int(ViewItem[i,3])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: `ViewItem[i][3]`

Comment: you have a function named TotalCost(), and a variable named TotalCost...

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I guess he only calls `TotalCost()` once, so it never notices that he can't call it again after it runs.

Comment: `TotalCost` might be a local variable that shadows the function name, which would prevent recursive calls but otherwise be harmless. It's hard to tell though given that the indentation is broken.

Comment: Maybe Barmar, it is hard to tell as chepner points out...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for accessing elements in nested lists is

```
variable[1stindex][2ndindex][3rdindex]...
```

so it should be:

```
TotalCost=TotalCost+int(ViewItem[i][3])
```

`1,3` is a tuple, which can't be used as a list index.